# Horizontal overflow on mobile site

Tags: css, mobile, scroll

jsfiddle.net/etto2sdt/

What I'm trying to do is having a touch scrollable div. The body is set to 100% and I want to be able to scroll the contents inside #testnavwrapper

But it's not working... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#testnavwrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

This will give you a horizontal scrollbar on the #testnavwrapper.

`width: 2000px`, as you put it, will have no effect as the overflow would occur on the body element (which has overflow set to `hidden`)

Hope it helps

Comment: Amazing, there was me just forcing it by having a px vs % in there. Works like a dream now, thanks :)

Comment: If it works, you might mark it as the correct answer. Thx :)